# React useRef returns error of Cannot read property 'style' of null on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with a component that controls smooth scrolling. When refreshing the page, I have zero issues but on RouteChanges I am getting a response of `Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Clearly and backed by the the error in the component of `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)` I know that on the route change the `ref` is not yet applied. However, I cannot figure out how to fix. Looking at other questions that are of a similar problem, they all suggest using `useEffect()`, which I am. What am I doing wrong?

The component is

```
const Scroll: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const windowSize = useWindowSize();
  const scrollingContainerRef = useRef();

  const data = {
    ease: 0.1,
    current: 0,
    previous: 0,
    rounded: 0,
  };

  const setBodyHeight = () => {
    if (isBrowser)
      document.body.style.height = `${
        scrollingContainerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().height // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

      }px`;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setBodyHeight();
  }, [windowSize.height]);

  const smoothScrollingHandler = () => {
    data.current = isBrowser && window.scrollY;
    data.previous += (data.current - data.previous) * data.ease;
    data.rounded = Math.round(data.previous * 100) / 103;
    scrollingContainerRef.current.style.transform = `translateY(-${data.previous}px)`; // Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

    requestAnimationFrame(() => smoothScrollingHandler());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => smoothScrollingHandler());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div ref={scrollingContainerRef}>{children}</div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: what if you use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect?

Comment: @ssBarBee. Tried that and still the same issue.

Comment: perhaps relatable: https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780

Comment: @ssBarBee. Yes, that works. Thank you so much. Did you want to put that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: sure @Darren thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the article https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780. It showcases how to use refs with useEffect.